# Is there a reliable order to the updateIds returned by `EKS.Client.list_updates()`?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-cli

I am using `EKS.Client.list_updates()` to get the updateIds for a managed nodegroup associated with an EKS cluster. I would like to use:

```py
client.list_updates(
    name=myCluster,
    nodegroupName=myNodegroup,
    maxResults=1
)
```

to get the last update to the nodegroup.

Can I rely on the order of the results to be ordered from most recent to least recent?

The [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.26.86/reference/services/eks/client/list_updates.html) does not mention any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further testing, I have concluded that there is no definite order to the updateIDs returned.